# MVC Ajax form does not hit controller, and loads page content instead

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to load a partial view,It is with MVC C#.

This is my Controller (called ArticlesController)

```
    [HttpPost]
    public PartialViewResult PaginatedArticles(int currentArticleCount, int currentPageN)
    {
       var model = new ArticlesViewModel();

       IEnumerable<IPublishedContent> ArticleItems = CurrentPage.Children().Where(x => x.DocumentTypeAlias == "article");

       var articles = _MapArticles.MapNewsItems(ArticleItems, Umbraco);

       var totalArticles = articles.Count();

       var totalPages = (int)Math.Ceiling((double)totalArticles / (double)pageSize);


       model.CurrentPageN = currentPageN;
       model.Articles = articles.Skip(currentArticleCount).Take(pageSize);

       return PartialView("_ArticleBoxes", model);
   }
```

My View where i call the controller.

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("PaginatedArticles", "Articles", null, new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod="POST", UpdateTargetId = "articleBoxesWrapper"}, new { currentArticleCount = Model.PageSize * i, currentPageN = i }))
{
     <input type="submit" value="@n">
}
```

Also tried with ajax.actionlink:

```
<li class="@isActive" >
        @Ajax.ActionLink(n.ToString(), "PaginatedArticles","Articles",null, new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", UpdateTargetId = "articleBoxesWrapper" }, new { currentArticleCount = Model.PageSize * i, currentPageN = i } )
</li>
```

**My Issue:**

It doesn't hit the controller AT ALL
Instead it updates the div with the entire page content.

I cannot fathom what i am doing wrong ?

Comment: Did you install Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Ajax to your project?

Comment: @AliZeinali yes, that has been installed.

Comment: any other Javascript console errors? Even an unrelated one might stop an ajax call from triggering (since that uses JavaScript) and therefore the form would just post back the whole page instead.

Comment: disabling other errors did not change anything. And it appears it is hitting the other action i have in the controller, instead of the one i need it to hit. Even though i have not set it to hit it.

Comment: what do you mean "disabling" errors? Either your code is throwing errors, or it isn't

Comment: It means that `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js.` is not loaded, or loaded incorrectly. But your method expects paramaters for `int currentArticleCount, int currentPageN` but neither your `Ajax.BeginForm()` or `Ajax.ActionLink()` are passing anything to the method (the last parameter adds html attributes not route values)

Comment: @ADyson i just cleaned the section of code that was throwing errors.